# Unable to use System.Data.SQLite after Nuget installing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have a "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)" project. I went to `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution...`.

I chose "Browse", found "System.Data.SQLite" and installed it.

It says it's successfully installed, and shows under "Dependencies".

However, when I type "using System.Data." it doesn't find it. And if I try to add it as a reference, it never finds it.

how do I add this to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Visual Studio needs to be restarted or it doesn't see it.

Comment: @DangerZone It appears so. I'm writing code and will compile/run it to see, but at least I can add a `using` statement for it

Comment: @DangerZone It built and ran, so yes, the restart fixed it

Comment: @Don Rhummy, thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.